# A self hosted Amazon Docker image error:This site can’t be reached

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy my Spring boot and react-based application on an Amazon EC2 instance. My health status has transitioned to a warning.

My logs of the aws ec2 instance are :

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-10-05T18:53:10.445Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.fullstack.FullstackApplication       : Starting FullstackApplication using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)
2023-10-05T18:53:10.449Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.fullstack.FullstackApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-05T18:53:10.884Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-10-05T18:53:10.885Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-10-05T18:53:15.413Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-05T18:53:15.432Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-05T18:53:15.711Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.amigoes.fullstack.customer.CustomerRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2023-10-05T18:53:15.712Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 238 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-10-05T18:53:15.795Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-05T18:53:15.823Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-05T18:53:16.087Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 224 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-05T18:53:21.480Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-05T18:53:21.563Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-05T18:53:21.563Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-10-05T18:53:21.849Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-05T18:53:21.857Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10659 ms
2023-10-05T18:53:22.467Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 9.16.3 by Redgate
2023-10-05T18:53:22.467Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See release notes here: https://rd.gt/416ObMi
2023-10-05T18:53:22.467Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : 
2023-10-05T18:53:22.480Z  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/fullstack-f15b80382c26-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/frontend-react-3d88b92cdce9-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/frontend-react-64e593b5f8a9-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/frontend-react-bd3ac2e1dd79-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/fullstack-0767fd89d97b-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/fullstack-6396590b65cf-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/fullstack-8c5a0a96b6c1-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
```

My Docker file of react is:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

ARG api_base_url

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i --silent

COPY . .
RUN echo "VITE_API_BASE_URL=${api_base_url}" > .env

EXPOSE 5173
 
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

My docker compose:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456789
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
  fullstack-api:
    container_name: fullstack-api
    image: ahmadmujtaba200210/fullstack
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer
    ports:
      - "8088:8080"
    networks:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
  fullstack-frontend-react:
    container_name: frontend-react
    image: ahmadmujtaba200210/fullstack-react
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: frontend/react
      args:
        api_base_url: http://localhost:8088
    ports:
      - "3000:5173"
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-api
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json file is :

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "fullstack-react",
      "image": "ahmadmujtaba200210/fullstack-react:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 5137
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "fullstack",
      "image": "ahmadmujtaba200210/fullstack:04.10.2023.05.02.43",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL",
          "value": "jdbc:postgresql://awseb-e-ewuh4fh3ed-stack-awsebrdsdatabase-pyslfllvhlal.cw2qjcr4sn8j.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/customer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to build docker image with aws database url which was successful but my frontend application is on react can understand why it is not working, why it is not being deployed?

Comment: are you running a graviton instance? Your container starts fine here. `exec format error` is indicative of that

Comment: yes I am running an EC2 instance

Comment: @SathyajithBhat is asking, do the processor architectures match?  You can get that error if you build on an ARM machine (like an M1 Mac) and run on an x86 EC2 instance, or if you build on an x86 machine but run on an ARM (Graviton) machine.

Comment: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

this is what I got when I did ssh into my aws instance and tried to manually pull that image (react-image)

Comment: suggest me the solution

Comment: why my post is showing -1 ? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down the issues and solve them step by step:

1. **Exec format error**:

   You have multiple log entries:

   ```
   exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
   ```

   This error usually indicates that there's a problem with the entry point script (`docker-entrypoint.sh`) for your container. The most common causes for this error include:

   - The entry point script does not have the executable permissions.
   - The entry point script has Windows-style line endings (if you developed on Windows) instead of UNIX-style line endings.

   To solve this:

   - Ensure the script has executable permissions:

     ```
     chmod +x /path/to/your/docker-entrypoint.sh
     ```
   - If you're developing on Windows, you can convert the line endings using tools like `dos2unix` or any text editor that allows you to convert line endings.
2. **Mismatched Ports**:

   In your `Dockerfile` for the React application, you're exposing port `5173`:

   ```
   EXPOSE 5173
   ```

   However, in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, the container port you're trying to map is `5137`:

   ```json
   {
     "hostPort": 80,
     "containerPort": 5137
   }
   ```

   This is a mismatch. You need to ensure that both the ports are the same, either `5173` or `5137`, whichever is the correct one.
3. **Environment Variable for React Frontend**:

   Your React frontend likely needs to know the URL of your backend API to make calls to it. In the Docker Compose file, you're passing this information as an argument to the Docker build:

   ```yaml
   build:
     args:
       api_base_url: http://localhost:8088
   ```

   This only works if you're building your Docker image every time you deploy, and that the API URL does not change. If you have a static API URL, it's better to pass it as an environment variable to the running container, similar to how you pass the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to your Spring Boot application.
4. **Networking on AWS**:

   Docker Compose creates a custom network for the services defined in a `docker-compose.yml` file, allowing them to communicate with each other using the service names as hostnames (e.g., `db` for the database, `fullstack-api` for the API). However, `Dockerrun.aws.json` doesn't create such a network by default.

   If your React frontend communicates with the Spring Boot backend, ensure they are on the same network, or the React frontend knows the correct URL to communicate with the backend.
5. **DevTools in Production**:

   The logs indicate that Spring Boot's DevTools is active:

   ```
   .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active!
   ```

   It's not recommended to have DevTools active in a production environment. Ensure that DevTools is not included in the production build of your application.
6. **Database Connection**:

   Ensure that the database hosted on RDS is accessible from the EC2 instance where your application is deployed. Security groups, VPC configurations, or the RDS instance's public accessibility setting can affect this.

After addressing these issues, try redeploying your application. If you continue to encounter issues, check the logs for any new or persisting errors.